# When is Android's backup service not available?

Tags: android, backup

The document [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html) states that:

> 'Data backup is not guaranteed to be available on all Android-powered
>   devices'

Are there any examples of when the backup service is not available on a device? Is the backup service guaranteed to be there if the user has installed the app via Google Play (i.e. they have a google account)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well, for one thing, it requires API Level 8 (Android 2.2) or greater, so currently about 6% of devices with Google Play can't use it.  Otherwise, I think it's a safe assumption that the vast majority of devices with 2.2+ and Google Play have access to it.

Comment: Yes, I understand that it's >= level 8, but that's not what I asked. Making assumptions always ends in tears. I want evidence so that I may make an informed decision.

Comment: @James It may not be what you meant to ask, but the information I provided answers the question you quite literally did ask (re-read your question if you don't believe me!)  The manufacturer and carrier have the ability to customize or remove the transport layer, so it's not guaranteed to be there. However, in my experience it usually is.